# Trying to draw my player and move him

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

I am working on a little project where I am trying to get a player in my 2D view (actually a circle) and let him move left to right, up and down flawless, also I want to be able to press 2 keys at ones so he moves sideways or something like that.

Also i want to be able to shoot with the player in a certain direction in a later state of the project (it could be important as of now)

I am doing this project because I want to learn how C++ OOP works.
The structure im having in my mind is simple :

```
Main > (Creates) > GameWindow
Main > (creates) > EntityManager > (creates) > Player 
Player > (creates via) > EnitityManager > Gun
Gun > (Creates via) > EntityManager > Bullet
```

Player can :
Walk up/down/left/right
Shoot.

So to get to the code, This is what I have in my FirstGame.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"
#include "EntityManager.h"

int main()
{
    // Create an entity manager
    EntityManager::Instance();

    // Display the window
    GameWindow::Instance().Run();
}
```

in my GameWindow.h I have :

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

class GameWindow
{
public:
    static GameWindow& Instance()
    {
        static GameWindow instance;
        return instance;
    }

    RenderWindow& GetRenderWindow();

    void Run();

private:
    static const int DEF_WIDTH = 1366;
    static const int DEF_HEIGHT = 720;

    GameWindow();
    GameWindow(const GameWindow&);
    GameWindow& operator=(const GameWindow&);
    ~GameWindow();

    string windowTitle;
    int windowWidth;
    int windowHeight;

    void Initialize();
    void DisplayWindow();
    void CheckWindowEvent();
};
```

and in my GameWindow.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"

RenderWindow renderWindow;
Event eventSF;

GameWindow::GameWindow()
{
    Initialize();
}


GameWindow::~GameWindow()
{

}

void GameWindow::Initialize()
{
    // Set width & height to default settings
    windowWidth = DEF_WIDTH;
    windowHeight = DEF_HEIGHT;

    // Create the render window
    renderWindow.create(VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), windowTitle, Style::Titlebar | Style::Close | Style::Resize);

    Cmd::WriteLine("GameWindow Initialized!");
}

RenderWindow& GameWindow::GetRenderWindow()
{
    return renderWindow;
}

void GameWindow::Run()
{
    // Loop until window has closed
    while (renderWindow.isOpen())
    {
        // Check current window events
        CheckWindowEvent();

        // Display window
        DisplayWindow();
    }
}

void GameWindow::DisplayWindow()
{
    // Display the render window
    renderWindow.clear();
    renderWindow.display();
}

void GameWindow::CheckWindowEvent()
{
    Event _event;
    while (renderWindow.pollEvent(_event))
    {
        // Request for closing the window
        if (_event.type == Event::Closed)
            renderWindow.close(); 
    }
}
```

and in my EntityManager.h I got :

```
#pragma once
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Player.h"

class EntityManager
{
public:
    static EntityManager& Instance()
    {
        static EntityManager instance = EntityManager();

        return instance;
    }


private:
    EntityManager();
    ~EntityManager();

    void Initialize();
};
```

and my EntityManager.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "EntityManager.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"
#include "Player.h"

EntityManager::EntityManager()
{
    Initialize();
}

EntityManager::~EntityManager()
{
}

void EntityManager::Initialize()
{
    Player::Create();
}
```

and now the Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Entity.h"

using namespace sf;

class Player: Entity
{
public:
    Player();
    ~Player();

    void GotDamage(int damage);
    static void Create();
    void Draw();
    void Shoot();
    void Move(float x, float y);
    void Controls(Event _eventSF);

private:
    string name;
    int health;

    Event eventSF;
    CircleShape playerVisual;

protected:
    void Initialize() override;
};
```

and last the Player.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

Player::Player()
{

}


Player::~Player()
{

}

void Player::Create()
{
    Player player;
    player.Initialize();
    player.Draw();
    player.Controls(player.eventSF);
}

void Player::Initialize()
{
    CircleShape playerVisual(50);
    playerVisual.setPosition(800, 450);
    playerVisual.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));

    Entity::Initialize();
}

void Player::Controls(sf::Event _eventSF)
{
    while(GameWindow::Instance().GetRenderWindow().isOpen())
    {
        while(GameWindow::Instance().GetRenderWindow().pollEvent(_eventSF))
        {
            switch(_eventSF.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    if (_eventSF.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                    {
                        Move(0,-1);
                    }
                    if (_eventSF.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
                    {
                        Move(0,1);
                    }
                    if (_eventSF.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    {
                        Move(-1,0);
                    }
                    if (_eventSF.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    {
                        Move(1,0);
                    }
                    if (_eventSF.key.code == sf::Keyboard::BackSpace)
                    {
                        GotDamage(20);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << " Checking Controls "  << endl;
}

void Player::Move(float _x, float _y)
{
    cout << "Move Player " << endl;
    playerVisual.move(_x, _y);
    Draw();
}

void Player::GotDamage(int _damage)
{
    //for some reason health is -858993460
    cout << "Your current health is " << Player::health << " you received " << _damage <<  " damage now you have "  << Player::health - _damage << " health left. " << endl;
    health -= _damage;
}

void Player::Draw()
{
    cout << "Draw Player" << endl;
    CircleShape visual(50);
    playerVisual.setPosition(800, 450);
    playerVisual.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));
    GameWindow::Instance().GetRenderWindow().draw(visual);
}
```

I know it is a lot but I hope someone can help me.

To repeat my goal :
I am trying to get my player to be drawn on the screen and let him move sideways and if possible diagonal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't made it clear exactly what your problem is. You want to move the player, but what about it isn't working?

Comment: And it looks to me like you're setting the position of the circle to `(800, 450)` every time you draw it.

Comment: What did you discover when you used the Debugger?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Oh i forgot, my player doesn't get drawn on my 2D screen, when i do the same line of code in the main, it works just fine, but when i do it in the Player.cpp it doesn't work.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews my Debugger told me "Player Moved" and "Player Drawn" but he didn't draw and im not sure he did move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add onto KeyHeart's answer.

I hacked up your code a bit and managed to get it working.

Keep in mind the scope of your variables. There's CircleShape playerVisual(50) in Player::Initialize() which is a local variable, but you already have a CircleShape playerVisual inside Player.h! So the former is unnecessary. Likewise in Player::Create() you create a local player object.

I don't have a full copy of your code, so I assume what you plan on doing is having EntityManager handle all existing entities, such as the player. Therefore you should have Player player declared in the EntityManager's header file. Thus calling the constructor, which I have taken everything from Player::Create() and placed it into Player::Player(). And this player will exist for lifespan of EntityManager.

The order in which you should be updating the buffer is:

```
renderWindow.clear()
renderWindow.draw()
renderWindow.display()
```

As you have it now, you draw() then clear() effectively displaying nothing.
There are many approaches, but the simplest would be adding a call to Player::Draw() in GameWindow::DisplayWindow(). Though GameWindow will need a player object to call Draw().

Regarding moving the player. Player::Controls contains what may be an infinite loop in a sense. The line while (GameWindow::Instance().GetRenderWindow().isOpen()) will continue to loop as long as the window is open thus can block anything else from updating, such as drawing.

Comment: Thanks Kookehs, i managed to get the infinite loop out of the game, and draw the player on the screen, still i cannot talk to player the player or use its private variables inside the player itself. so when i define SetRadius(50); and use that in the draw function it works.

but when i make an 

int radius;

and do SetRadius(radius);
It changed the frame after i set the radius = 50; to 0.

Not sure why this is hapenning i though once you defined your variable you're done with it?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be drawing playerVisual rather than visual which exists locally inside the Player::Draw() function?

Also shouldn't you call Player::Draw() in GameWindow::Run(), since you call GameWindow::DisplayWindow() which will update the screen. Calling Player::Draw() in Player::Move() limits drawing of the sprite only to when it moves. The results of this would be the sprite existing only in frames in which it moves otherwise an empty canvas.

Comment: Hmm that second part sounds interesting, i was assuming that if the draw doesnt get called it just stays where it is. so i was trying to get the lowest possible events for the best results.

Im gonna try that and edit if it works :)

Comment: Didnt work, my Player::Draw now looks like this :

void Player::Draw()
{
 cout << "Draw Player" << endl;
 GameWindow::Instance().GetRenderWindow().draw(playerVisual);
}

I figured out that i tried to make a new player circle inside of the draw and set his position, kinda strange, but i am not sure how to get to playerVisual from my Player class.